# How to do a self cartesian product over the different partitions of a Spark dataset?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I need to compare the different rows of a dataset two to two. Ideally, I would do a self cartesian product of the dataset, then I would remove the duplicated comparisons (as `A, B` is the same as `B, A`) and finally I would do a `map` to decide whether each pair of rows are equals or not. However, it would result on a huge amount of rows and I can't afford the computational cost it would have.

In order to bring down as much as possible the resultant amount of rows, I would like to sort the rows and only apply the self cartesian product over different subsets of the whole dataset. For example, the subsets would be the following ones:

- From row 0 to 100
- From row 50 to 150
- From row 100 to 200
- ....

By this way, I would compare each row with its neigbours and the final amount of rows to compare would be much smaller than if I would do the self cartesian product over the whole dataset.

#### My attempt

I've actually implemented a solution but for some reason it takes a lot of time even if the dataset is small.

Firstly, I sort and zip the dataset in order to identify each column.

```
val sortedByTitle = journalArticles.orderBy("title")
val withIndex = sortedByTitle.rdd.zipWithIndex().toDF("article", "index").as[IndexArticle]
```

Then, I've made a function to do the division and self cartesian product:

```
def divideAndCartesian(data: Dataset[IndexArticle], fromIndex: Long, divisionSize: Int): Dataset[CartessianIndexArticles] = {
  val division = data.filter(x => x.index >= fromIndex && x.index < fromIndex + divisionSize)
  if(division.count() == 0) Seq.empty[(JournalArticle, Long, JournalArticle, Long)].toDF("article1", "index1", "article2", "index2").as[CartessianIndexArticles]
  else
    division.crossJoin(division).toDF("article1", "index1", "article2", "index2").as[CartessianIndexArticles].union(divideAndCartesian(data, fromIndex + (divisionSize / 2), divisionSize))
}
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: In my answer below, by "I would do a map to decide whether each pair of rows are equals or not" I assumed you were not looking to filter out exact duplicates, are you?

Comment: or you could groupby() ->agg()->where()

Comment: @PascalSoucy no, I'm not looking for exact duplicates. I'll read about what you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read about `Approximate Similarity Join` using Locality Sensitive Hashing. As per the documentation:

> The general idea of LSH is to use a family of functions (“LSH
>   families”) to hash data points into buckets, so that the data points
>   which are close to each other are in the same buckets with high
>   probability, while data points that are far away from each other are
>   very likely in different buckets.

Specifically, the Approximate Similarity Join:

> Approximate similarity join takes two datasets and approximately
>   returns pairs of rows in the datasets whose distance is smaller than a
>   user-defined threshold. Approximate similarity join supports both
>   joining two different datasets and self-joining. Self-joining will
>   produce some duplicate pairs.

In short, LSH will bucketize your rows to avoid comparing all possible pairs. After you do the Approximate Similarity Join for instance, if you use [Bucketed Random Projection for Euclidean Distance](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#bucketed-random-projection-for-euclidean-distance)

```
val joined = model.approxSimilarityJoin(data, data, 2.5)
```

All pairs in `joined` that are within 2.5 of distance will be returned. It is up to you then to decide if that approximation is good enough to filter out duplicates, or if you then want to calculate the exact similarity between the rows.